# How can I search a part of a string and display it?

Tags: c, string

I have this code here to search a string in a file and display it. How can I edit this piece of code to make it possible to search just a part of this string?
say, the file contains the author "dennis zill", if I search "zill" I want the code to display "dennis zill".

[image: a sample of the file content]

```
int searchauthor(FILE *ptr)    //searching starts
    {
        int save;
        char de;
        char in_name[30];
        int flag = 1;
    
        save = readbooks();
        ptr = fopen("books info.txt", "r");
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n Enter the name of the author: ");
        gets(in_name);
        printf("-------------------------------------------------");
    
        for(int i = 0; i < save; i++){
            if(strcmpi(in_name, info[i].bauthor) == 0){
                printf("\n Book name: %s\n Price: %u\n Number of books available: %u\n Number of pages: %u\n-------------------------------------------------", info[i].bname, info[i].price, info[i].numavail, info[i].bpages);
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    
        if (flag == 1){
            printf("\n Not found.\n Do you want to try another search [Y/N]? ");
            scanf("%c", &de);
            if(de == 'y' || de == 'Y'){
                system("cls");
                in_name[MAX] = reset(in_name);
                fclose(ptr);
                return 2;
            }
            else if(de == 'n' || de == 'N'){
                printf("\n You will be redirected to main menu");
                for(int k = 1; k <= 5; k++){
                    Sleep(300);
                    printf(".");
                }
                system("cls");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    
        printf("\n\n Do you want to try another search [Y/N]? ");
        scanf("%c", &de);
    
        if (de == 'y' || de == 'Y') {
            system("cls");
            in_name[MAX] = reset(in_name);
            return 2;       //return 2 to case 3 to search again
        }
        else if (de == 'n' || de == 'N') {
            system("cls");
            printf("\n You will be redirected to main menu");
            for(int k = 1; k <= 5; k++){
                Sleep(300);
                printf(".");
            }
            system("cls");
            return 1;
        }
    }  //searching ends
```

Comment: try using `strstr()` or `strcasestr()` rather than `strcmp()`

Comment: Please add plain text as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: @tstanisl     If I use strstr() it just displays all the contents in the file!!

Comment: @AliElneklawy, did you try `strstr(info[i].bauthor, in_name) != NULL` ?

Comment: @tstanisl     done. it works! can I make it case-insensitive?

Comment: @AliElneklawy, use `strcasestr` if its available on your platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
if(strcmp(in_name, info[i].bauthor) == 0){
```

It will succeed only on a full match.

Rather that using `strcmp` use `strstr` (or its case-insensitive variant `strcasestr()` if it's available).

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

The `haystack` is the full authors name, `needle` the user's input.
Function returns `NULL` on failure so it's enough to check if non-NULL was returned.

```
if(strstr(info[i].bauthor, in_name) != NULL){
```